# Swift3 scheduledTime seconds running too fast when timing for longer

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am using Xcode with swift 3 to make a basic timer. I have a timer label connected to my view controller which updates the label every second. When timing for a longer period, the seconds run up faster (see GIF).

Can anyone explain what i am doing wrong, or what i should not be doing (wrong approach, better functions)?

This is the relevant code:

```
@IBAction func startButtonTabbed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if (sender == startButton) {

        let now              = Date()
        let formatter        = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        start_time           = formatter.string(from:now)

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    } else {

            timer.invalidate()
    }

}
func timerAction() {

    time += 1;
    updateTimingLabel(seconds: time)

}

func updateTimingLabel(seconds: Int) {

    self.timerLabel.text = stringFromTimeInterval(interval: TimeInterval(time)) as String

}

func stringFromTimeInterval(interval: TimeInterval) -> NSString {

    let ti = NSInteger(interval)
    let seconds = ti % 60
    let minutes = (ti / 60) % 60
    let hours = (ti / 3600)

    return NSString(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d",hours,minutes,seconds)

}
```

This is what happens:

[image]

Comment: The answer from @Ivan Skrobot is correct. I just copied and pasted your code here in a test project and could reproduce the behaviour tapping two times on button. Tapping once is counting correctly. And as many as you tap on button, it goes faster and faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you pressed start button 2 times and you scheduled two timers.
Try this

```
@IBAction func startButtonTabbed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if (sender == startButton) {


        if  !timer.isValid{

            let now              = Date()
            let formatter        = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
            start_time           = formatter.string(from:now)



        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    } else {

        timer.invalidate()
    }

}
```

Comment: That seems plausible :) I will run the sim for a while and let you know and accept.

Comment: This seemed to be the problem. Thank you!